# How to incorporate initial distribution into probability of ultimate extinction of a branching process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a branching Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$, where $X_0 = 1$ and the offspring distribution is given by $$p(0) = \frac 1 6, p(1) = \frac 1 2, p(2) = \frac 1 3.$$ The number of offspring produced by each individual is independent of the number of offspring produced by other individuals.

$(a)\quad$ Find the probability of ultimate extinction.

Now, suppose that the offspring distribution remains unchanged, but that $X_0$ has a geometric distribution with PMF $$\mathbb{P}(X_0 = m) = (1 - \pi)\pi^{m - 1}\ \forall\ m \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$$

$(b)\quad$ Find the probability of ultimate extinction.

**My working**

$(a)\quad$ We can clearly see that the mean number of offspring produced by each individual is more than one, so the probability of ultimate extinction is less than one. Let this probability be $s$ and we have $$\frac 1 6 + \frac 1 2 s + \frac 1 3 s^2 = s.$$ Now, solving this equation will give $$s = \frac 1 2.$$

---

**Edit**

Following the discussion in the comments, my working for part $(b)$ is as follows:

The mean number of offspring produced by each individual is still more than one, so the probability of ultimate extinction, $s$, is still less than one.

$$\begin{aligned}
\because \rho_{10} & = \frac 1 2\\[1 mm]
& = (\rho_{20})^{\frac 1 2}\\[1 mm]
& = (\rho_{30})^{\frac 1 3}\\[1 mm]
& = \dots,\\[1 mm]
\therefore \rho_{n0} & = 2^{-n}\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+.\\[1 mm]
\implies s & = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \mathbb{P}(X_0 = n) \rho_{n0}\\[1 mm]
& = (1 - \pi) \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \pi^{n - 1}\left(2^{-n}\right)\\[1 mm]
\end{aligned}$$

However, this is where I am stuck. We can observe that the sum is the sum to infinity of a geometric series with first term $\frac 1 2$ and common ratio $\frac 1 2 \pi$. Since the common ratio is not less than one, this sum is not finite i.e. $s = \infty$, but how can we have infinite probability? Moreover, this contradicts my initial statement that the ultimate probability of extinction is less than one, but I am unable to figure out where I have gone wrong, so any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You working for (a) is correct. For (b), again try to write out an expression of the moment generating function of the offspring distribution based on a given initialization with geometric distribution.

Comment: @Tab1e before I try that, may I clarify two things? Firstly, what does $X_0 = 1$ actually mean? Does it mean that there is only one person in the entire population at the start? Secondly, do you mean probability generating function instead of moment generating function?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Maybe we are using different conventions, but I mean the $\varphi(s) = 1/6+1/2s+1/3s^2$ you found in part (a).

Comment: @Tab1e I see. If $X_0 = 2$, then is that equivalent to letting $s$ be $2s$ i.e. $\frac 1 6 + \frac 1 2 (2s) + \frac 1 3 (2s)^2 = 2s$? I am not sure how to proceed when $X_0 \neq 1$...

Comment: Not really. Let $\pi_0$ be the solution to $1/6+1/2s+1/3s^2=s$. Then if $X_0=2$, the answer would be $\pi_0^2$. Notice that for $X_0 = 2$, it is essentially to consider 2 independent copies of the original branching process at the same time with $X_0=1$.

Comment: If you are not familiar with this, maybe first learn the basics like the properties of the moment generating function of the offspring distribution, and why the probability of extinction follows the solution $\varphi(s) = s$.

Comment: @Tab1e I have since had a chance to re-work part $(b)$ and I have edited my post accordingly. However, I believe it is still incorrect. Would you mind taking some time to look through it and let me know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the common ratio is not less than one? $\pi$ has to be in the range of $(0,1]$ to be a geometric distribution, and $\pi/2 \in (0,1/2]$.

Comment: Oh did you consider $\pi$ as the constant $\pi$? No $\pi$ has to be a variable here because otherwise the probability of $X_0=m$ would be negative for any $m$.

Comment: @Tab1e HAHAHA… *facepalm* I see. That makes so much more sense. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. Nice work!